# How to use sensitive data in .vimrc?

Tags: vimrc, security

I want to have my .vimrc synced through github so it has to be public file, but at the same time i have to put some sensitive data (for example db passwords/hosts for dbext.vim) in it, without giving them away to others. What is the best way and how to do it?

Comment: Does your solution have to use public github repos or are private and/or self-hosted repos fine?

Comment: I'd like to have it in public place, except the small fragments with passwords of course.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can include another file using the `source` command. Simply put this at the top of your vimrc:

```
source($MYVIMRC . ".private")
```

Assuming your vimrc is `~/.vimrc`, that will expand to `~/.vimrc.private`. From now on, you can define variables in that file like this:

```
let my_db_password = "bacon"
```

Then you can simply refer to them by name in your main vimrc.

## Notes

- You can call the private vimrc file whatever you want, it can even be in a different directory.
- If you want to use `~` in the path, you will need to use `expand()`. For example: `source expand("~/.private-vimrc")`
- To concatenate the variable's value with a string, use the `.` operator. For example: `"jdbc:mysql://example.com/waffles?user=admin&password=" . my_db_password`

Answer (score 0):

For newer vim versions do not use brackets:

```
source $MYVIMRC.private
```